# Save selections made in Listview and pass to calling activity?

Tags: android, listview

My app has a main screen which has a button(Select Items) on click of it starts one more activity which shows the listview of items. User is allowed to make multiple selections in the list view and clicks on 'Apply Filters' button. After clicking the apply filters the user is taken back to main screen. If user once again clicks the button(Select Items) user should be shown with previously selected values already checked.

How do I achieve this scenario in my android app?

Kindly help.

Thank you in advance.

Pramod K

Comment: use startActivityforResult to launch the next Activity and override onActivityResult for the data to be passed to the Main Screen[further reading here...](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a field `selected` to your items and in the adapter you can style the view based on this selected field.

Answer (score 0):

Create object that has all data of each row of listView. store a boolean and named it selected in the object field. when the user select the listView item toggle the selected. send the list of object between activities. populate the listView according to the selected

GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

just make ArrayList that stores itemids of ListView.
On click of any list item, check if that item is already in ArrayList then do nothing otherwise add into ArrayList.

in this way you can get selected items ids of listview

try this way hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

To return a result (in your case the list of the selected filters) to activity A from an activity B, you can start the activity B using startActivityForResult.

documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities 
The setResult should be used to pass the list of selected filters ids to the activity A.

To open activity B with some filters enable, probably you should simply put extras in the intent, e.g. with a list of the last selected filters ids.

documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent